# Regex match unwanted characters at the end of the string

Tags: regex, match

I use a regex in PHP that looks like this:

```
"/(word|another)\b/"
```

- When I match it to `word` it matches which I expect.
- When I match it to `wordabc` it does not match which is also correct for me.
- However, when I match it to `word.jpg` it match which I did not expect.

I don't want it to match `word.jpg`, just characters that ends with `word` or `another`.

My guess is that `\b` is not what I need?

*By the way, I match against 100 words and I've shortened it down here*

Comment: Try `(?:word|another)(?!\S)` instead. Word boundaries match a position where a character from `\w` meets a character from `\W` or one of the ends.

Comment: @revo Yes, that worked!